# Phonegap jquery ajax not working on phone

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cors

I recently try to build a little Phonegap application for android.
I managed to make everything works on my computer, but the ajax not working on my android phone.

My jquery ajax request:

```js
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: target_url,
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: "loginSuccess",
  error: loginError,
 });
```

Where target_url is: http://username:password@myip/htpassword/login.php
I'm using http authentication.
I also enabled the jquery cors support:

```js
$.support.cors = true;
```

And add my ip at config.xml:

```html
<access origin="<myip>" />
```

I'm tested that my application has internet connection!
I've tried several solutions but neither of them worked for me.
Any idea why my application couldn't connect to my xampp server from my phone?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you put that ajax call ?? inside device ready? or jquery ready?? or any other method? Can you check for errors in eclipse logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the auth to the `ajax` request instead of the url:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://myip/htpassword/login.php',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "loginSuccess",
    error: loginError,
});
```

Comment: Yes I've tried, but that way, the site shows me the standard http authentication popup. Maybe something messed up with my xampp config?